# Extend PHP Array with __toString()

Tags: php, arrays, tostring, extending

Is there a way to extend the native PHP array with a __toString() function/method?

I would like to be able to do

```
$a = array($x, $y, $z);
echo $a;
```

This should neither complain with a `Array to string conversion` notice nor the dull output of `Array` but instead do whatever I implement in the __toString() method of the array.

(In the __toString I would do something like iterate over the array and call __toString() on each element and concatenate that together to a string that describes the whole array.)

(I know that this can be done through e.g. a wrapper object, that's not the question. I want to tweak PHP on a more subtle level.)

Comment: Not natively without an extension - you can use ArrayObject

Comment: Use `echo implode('',$a);` ?

Comment: Using `implode()` might result in something unrecoverable if the data contains csv metadata - `serialize()` is safer. However to use an arbitrary encoding scheme, `array_reduce()` might be the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Php arrays are not objects, it's an ordered map. The most relevant documentation is maybe the one concerning [Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php)

As mike said, the only way to add a method for array manipulation is using `ArrayObject` which is closer to array than what you can find in other languages.

But:

`ArrayObject` implies the use of [`Iterator`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.iterator.php#class.iterator), but it's OO.